# How to set PHP Prepared Statement param to output of mysql function return

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In below example 3rd parameter is MySQL function

> generateProductCode(".$obj->a.")

is function which will be returning string as output after execution in MySQL. How to bind MySQL function output after execution as parameter in prepared statement?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product(`a`, `b`, `c`) as ( ?, ?, ?);"
$types = "ids";
$params = [$obj->a, $obj->b , "generateProductCode(".$obj->a.")"];
```

I know, we can do that by running SQL separately.
With normal sql query below query works

```
"INSERT INTO product(`a`, `b`, `c`) as (".$obj->a.",".$obj->b.",generateProductCode(".$obj->a."))";
```

Comment: Have you tried using `generateProductCode($obj->a)` (i.e. without the quotes)

Comment: No. Then how to pass $obj->a param value to generateProductCode if i remove the qoutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use your `generateProductCode` function call inside your query and provide the parameter as usual with the `?` marker.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product(a, b, c) as ( ?, ?, generateProductCode(?));"
$params = [$obj->a, $obj->b , $obj->a];
```